# Return two values mapped from a content response to completion handler

Tags: swift, return-value, return-type, completionhandler

This return is sending back a single string, the `accessToken` from the `ContentResponse`:

```
return body.encodeResponse(for: request)
     .map { $0.body.buffer }
     .flatMap { buffer in
             return request.client.post(url, headers: self.callbackHeaders) { $0.body = buffer }
     }.flatMapThrowing { response in
             return try response.content.get(ContentResponse.self)
     }.map { $0.accessToken }
```

which is being received in the completion handler here:

```
return try self.fetchToken(from: request).flatMap { accessToken in
```

How can I send back two strings - both the `accessToken` and the `refreshToken` from the `ContentResponse`?

Thanks so much for any help in how to structure this!

Comment: Is there a reason where you have `.map { $0.accessToken }` you can't have `.map { ($0.accessToken, $0.refreshToken) }`? This results in an `Array<(String, String)>`

Comment: You'll have to alter the completion handler `.flatMap { tokens in ` and refer to them by `tokens.accessToken` and `tokens.refreshToken` in the closure body.

Comment: Ugh my edit of my first comment got lost:  `.map { (accessToken: $0.accessToken, refreshToken: $0.refreshToken) }`? This results in an `Array<(accessToken: String, refreshToken: String)>`

Comment: if `fetchToken` currently returns `[String]`, you'll need to alter it to return `[(accessToken: String, refreshToken: String)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define and use a `struct` to return, but for one-off cases like this, I usually just go with a tuple with named members:

```swift
return body.encodeResponse(for: request)
     .map { $0.body.buffer }
     .flatMap { buffer in
             return request.client.post(url, headers: self.callbackHeaders) { $0.body = buffer }
     }.flatMapThrowing { response in
             return try response.content.get(ContentResponse.self)
     }.map { (accessToken: $0.accessToken, refreshToken: $0.refreshToken) } // <<- This is changed line
```

That will result in a return type of `[(accessToken: String, refreshToken: String)]` instead of `[String]`, so the return type of `fetchToken(from:)` will have to be changed to match.

Then the code where you call it looks like this:

```swift
return try self.fetchToken(from: request).flatMap { tokens in // <<- renamed to indicate it contains more than one value
   /* 
    refer to tokens.accessToken and tokens.refreshToken in whatever 
    code goes here 
   */
   ...
}
```